# Query from Kibana To Python?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana-7

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/trim
{
  "description" : "trims my name field",
  "processors" : [ {
      "trim" : {
        "field": "country"
      }
  } ]
}
```

`POST suppliers/_update_by_query?pipeline=trim`

I want the syntax of Python for the above Kibana Syntax

Comment: Why just you dont use Postman? put your curl and convert to python script

Comment: Or the python client? If I can manage it you can ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

I use postman and curl.trillworks.com

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{\n  "description" : "trims my name field",\n  "processors" : [ {\n      "trim" : {\n        "field": "country"\n      }\n  } ]\n}'

response = requests.put('http://localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/trim', headers=headers, data=data)
```

But maybe you should check python ES client

Answer (score 0):

For Python you need to import certain libraries

```
from elasticsearch.client.ingest import IngestClient
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es=Elasticsearch()
p = IngestClient(es)


body = {
        "description" : "trims my name field",
        "processors": [
            {
                "trim": {
                    "field": "country"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
p.put_pipeline(id="trim",body=body)
es.update_by_query(index="suppliers",pipeline="trim")
```